# How to add two tables data into a Crystal Report in c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, multiple-tables, dynamically-generated

I am using Access database as datasource. There are two tables in my database . One is Product Table and Invoice table. Invoice table has a productId which is actually Id in the product table. I want to show the product name instead of id dynamicaly according my runtime query. How can i do in c# ? Any one have suggestions Please

Comment: What have you tried so far? What queries are you using?  Please edit your question and provide more details and show your work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view between Product and Invoice then bind the view to the Crystal Report. Depending on your needs you don't need to write any extra code to do this.

Comment: Thanx for replying to this. My problem is in the c# code I have a DataTable and I add dynamic data to the this DataTable. It has the data which I expected. But the thing is when I set it as a datasource to the report , the report will not display only that rows. There are new additional rows inserting to the report.

Comment: If you show some example code that would help clarify the issue.